# Total weight of inputs to a neuron in ANN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

In ANN, we know that to make it "learn", we need to adjust the weights of the inputs to a particular neuron.

```
total_input=summation(w(j,i).a(j))
```

During adjustment, some weights are to be reduced while others to be increased.
Is the total weight of all j inputs to the i-th neuron should be 1?

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no reason for the weights in the linear layer (a.k.a. *dense* or *fully-connected* layer) to sum up to anything specific, such as 1.0. They are usually initialized with small random numbers (so initial sum is unlikely to be 1.0) and then get tweaked somehow (not completely independently, but at least differently).

If the neural network doesn't use any regularization, it's often possible to train the network to large weight values, much larger than 1.0 (see also [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4272/130598)).

There are particular cases, when an analogous condition is true, for example [softmax layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function), which mathematically guarantees that the sum of outputs is 1.0. But the linear layer doesn't guarantee anything like that.